# Django Url not resolving when passing query parameters

Tags: python, django, url

project urls.py:

```
url(r'^landlord/',include('Landlord.urls',namespace="landlord")),
```

landlord app urls.py:

```
 url(r'^edit/$', views.edit_property, name="edit_property"),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/$', views.edit_property_form, name="edit_property_form"),
```

The url written in the browser is "**landlord/edit/?id=1**". But it is resolving to first url only.

Comment: Resolves to views.edit_property only even though parameter is passed

Comment: If you're using a form, don't put the values in the URL anyway. Get them from the request body.

Comment: I am asking the user if needs to edit it. If he clicks edit then i am redirecting to a page with the id he wants to edit. So i want to pass id as a query parameter.

Comment: In that case I would link them to the page `landlord/edit/1/`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexHall i will use that.

Answer (score 3):

`/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/` is not a query parameter, it's part of the main URL. It's expecting a URL like `landlord/edit/1/`.